# Intelllj Build error message not understood

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Out of the blue ( surly I messed up something :) ), I am getting build errors on both Intellij build command and maven install command.

I guess that fixing one of them - will help the rest to be fixed as well.

So for example I get

> Error:(8, 30) java: package responsepojos.resource does not exist

on a AzureGetAllSubscriptionResourcesRequestStepsHandler.java which has

```
import responsepojos.resource.AzureResources;
```

and the project structure is as follows:

[image]

IntelliJ detects every identifier! For example - if I'll remove this import clause, IntelliJ automatically adds it back to the file.

Or if I ctrl+click on AzureResources identifier inside the code, IntelliJ takes me to to the correct class.

And following are many "cannot find symbol" and "package does not exist" errors.

Please don't send me automatically to "duplications". I have searched them and didn't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to share your entire build path configuration for anyone to be able to help.  We can't see how your IDE is configured, nor how things are arranged on your disk.  If this started happening "out of the blue" and was working previously, you changed something but without access to your computer it's unlikely anyone can guess what you changed.

Comment: @JimGarrison Do you mean you need the "output path" from the "project settings --> modules --> Paths" ? it is "C:\Users\aaa\IdeaProjects\Poc\target\classes". If not - please let me know better. Do you need also all the dependencies?

Comment: maybe modifier issues on package level?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the jar to an Artifactory and importing it from there via the pom file instead of importing the jar via Project Structure build path fixed the issue.
Have no idea why didn't it work before..